# maven version ranges do not behave as expected

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-3, maven

i know version ranges have problems when the maven standard versioning is not followed correctly. But the repositories are under our control, so we can enforce compatible versioning.
this is the code:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.intellimate.izou</groupId>
     <artifactId>sdk</artifactId>
     <version>[0.5.0, 1.0.0)</version>
</dependency>
```

right now it resolves to 0.9.0, but our latest is 0.9.1. i have already deleted the repo in the .m2 folder, but it redownloades the 0.9.0. if i directly target 0.9.1 it downloads the correct version. I am using intellij and maven 3, if that is important. what is wrong?

Edit: we really do not want to abolish version-ranges, until now it just worked and was a real help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i am really sorry for everybody experiencing the same problem...i just reinstalled maven and re-imported the project back into intellij-idea and it magically solved the problem.